# RestClient Digest Authentication C#

Tags: c#, post, hash, postman

I am trying to make a post request using RestClient with Digest Authentication .
But I keep getting error :

Cannot load all required data from authenticateHeader. Data: Realm="api domain"&Nonce="7fe0990c20aaa812c5a0a725e3a01423"&Qop="""

My code

```
          var client = new RestClient("ApiUrlPath"); 

            client.Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator("username","Password");

            client.UseUtf8Json();

            client.Timeout = -1;

            var request = new RestRequest();
            
            request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
            request.AddParameter("id", "2");

            var response =  client.Execute(request);
```

The request works in postman

Comment: Can you show us the Postman request?

Comment: The Postman will look more like this = https://www.postman.com/fixapost/workspace/np-public/request/18685130-cec83ec8-050d-4242-963b-ea22c9228a7c , with the correct url ,username and password